# In react js, using creating website like e-commerce. How to create and lock a unique domain name?

Tags: reactjs, browser, server, web-applications, hosting

In local i created web application. How to deploy it. How to lock a unique brand name in domain which is not available for others.

If any one created own application and runs on server, please guide me how to lock domain name and host on the server

Comment: maybe buy the domain?